# How to speed up append in Python?

Tags: python, append

My code is something like this:

```
def fun -> list:
    array = ... # creating of array
    return array

def fun2:
    array2 = []
    # some code
    for i in range(some_value):
        array2.append(fun)
```

Note that it isn't known how many values function **fun** returns in each step of the algorithm so it is impossible to allocate **array2** at the beginning. Is there any way how to fasten this performance?

Comment: That's a very broad question, especially without a concrete example. Please provide more information or an example of input / output

Comment: I appreciate your may be trying to create a minimal example, but that is not all valid Python, and it's left your actual question completely unclear. Is `fun` called for each iteration of the `for` loop with a different argument?

Comment: What do you want to speed up? And if `fun` can contain multiple elements, wouldn't you want to use `extend(...)` rather than `append(...)`?

Comment: I suspect the speed of `list.append()` is not actually your bottle neck, it's a highly optimised O(1) operation ran in C. It's likely that something within `fun()` is slow but I have not idea what without seeing the actual function and the passed arguments

Comment: @holdenweb, yes, thank you, I swapped extend and append. I'm sorry.

Comment: @Chris_Rands: Yes, **fun** is called in every loop with different arguments.

Comment: Also, beware that there _is_ an `array` type in Python, but you actually appear to be using lists.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [time complexity table](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) of different python operations on lists, you can see that that the speed of appending k elements to a list is always the same regardless to the number of elements to append.